# Stick footer on bottom window when there's no content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and I want to stick my footer on the bottom of the window, after few hours trying and searching on internet I'm not having any progression and I feel stuck on this, so that's why I'm asking to you:

How do I manage to put the footer on the bottom of the window when content is empty?

The solution must be responsive, because the webpage is most used on mobile phones. I have tried `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` on the footer but stills not working, if someone can help me I would appreciate so much :)

When I'm saying content I mean there is any `.product-container`.

Thank you for reading.

**There's my code:**

I have created a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/PKD6URWGan).

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" style="">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 hiddemobile">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 separate">
                <img style="width: 135px;" src="./img/logo.gif">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <ul class=" nav navbar-nav navbar-right margin-t-10">
                    <li><span>Warenwert: 999,99 €</span></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown  ">
                      <a href="#" class="padding-r-0 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart icon-flipped"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse r-paddingmobile l-paddingmobile">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">All products <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Super mega category</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Golosinas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">category</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Super mega category</a></li>        
                  </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </nav>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>    
        </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row ">      
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 padding-5 ">
                <div class="product-container">
                    <a href="#product">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 absolute-top padding-5 padding-r-10">
                            <div class="f-right">
                                <span class="bullet green">⬤<span>
                            </span></span></div>
                        </div>
                        <img class="col-xs-12" src="./img/product.jpg">
                    </a>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 bg-faded-white padding-t-5 padding-b-5   ">
                        <div class="row">
                            <a href="#product">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-7  padding-8-l-mobile padding-8-r-mobile">Artikelname</div>
                            <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 fullmex-color padding-8-l-mobile padding-8-r-mobile"> 99999,99€ </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2 padding-b-5 padding-r-10 padding-8-l-mobile padding-8-r-mobile">
                                <span class="f-right glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart icon-flipped fullmex-color"></span> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 footer">
        <div class="row">       
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="">
                 <ul class="hlist">
                    <li><a href="#">Datenshuttz</a></li><li>|</li>
                    <li><a href="#">AGB</a></li><li>|</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li><li>|</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
                  </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="">
                 <ul class="hlist pull-right f-left-mobile">
                    <li><a>© FULLMEX Advertising media fullservice</a></li>
                    <li class="hiddemobile" style="padding-left: 15px"><a>powered by</a></li>
                    <li class="hiddemobile"><a><img class="fullmex-fill-hover" src="http://aramark.fullserviceshop.dev/store/modern/img/Fullmex-Logo-2c.svg" alt="Fullmex"></a></li>
                  </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

body { background-color: #fff; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }

.separate {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.t-algin-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.color-light {
  color: #bebebe;
}
.font-light {
  font-family: RobotoLight;
}
.font-medium {
  font-family: RobotoMedium;
}
.article-title {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.article-num {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #bebebe;
}
.article-desc {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.product-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}

.absolute-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.absolute-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.product-container .glyphicon {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.product-container .glyphicon:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.footer > div > div{
  min-height: 50px;
  color: #bebebe;
}
.footer ul {
    display:table-row;
}
.footer ul li
{
    display: table-cell;
    height: 50px;
    list-style-type: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.footer ul li a {
    color: #bebebe;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.footer ul li a:hover {
  color: var(--main-color);
}
.product-image .img-responsive {
    margin: 0 auto;

}
.brand {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    display: block;
}
.no-borders {
  border: none;
}
.btn-custom {
  border: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.btn-1 {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  color: #fff;
}
.btn-1:hover {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  color: #fff;
}
.btn-2 {
  background-color: rgb(50,50,50);
  color: #fff;
}
.btn-2:hover {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  color: #fff;
}
.glyphicon.active {
  color: var(--main-color);
}
.border-default{
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}
.border-b-default {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}
.border-b-fullmex {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--main-color);
}
.border-fullmex {
  border: 1px solid var(--main-color);
}
.white-bg-hover:hover {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
.white-bg-active:focus {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}

.mini-menu {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mini-menu:not(.collapsed) .glyphicon {
  color: var(--main-color) !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: rgb(50,50,50);
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  height: 3px;
  color: #bebebe;
}


.navbar-nav > li > a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a:after {
  content: '';
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 1px;
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: var(--main-color);
}
.vcenter {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: none;
}
.profile-info {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 75px;
}
.profile-info .glyphicon {
  color: white;
}
.profile-info .icon {
  height: 75px;
  line-height:  63px;
}
.bg-blue {
  background-color: #00c0ef;
}
.border-blue {
  border: 1px solid #00c0ef;
}
.white {
  color: #ffff;
}
.bg-red {
  background-color: #dd4b39;
}
.border-red {
  border: 1px solid #dd4b39;
}
.bg-orange {
  background-color: #f39c12;
}
.border-orange {
  border: 1px solid #f39c12;
}
.bg-green {
  background-color: #00a65a;
}
.border-green {
  border: 1px solid #00a65a;
}
.padding-5 {
  padding: 5px;
}
.padding-b-10 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.padding-t-10 {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.padding-t-5 {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.padding-r-5 {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.navbar {
  min-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.margin-5 {
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}
.margin-t-5 {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.margin-t-10 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.padding-b-5 {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.padding-l-0 {
  padding-left: 0px !important;
}
.padding-l-5 {
  padding-left: 5px !important;
}
.padding-l-7 {
  padding-left: 7px !important;
}
.padding-l-15 {
  padding-left: 15px !important;
}
.padding-r-0 {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
.padding-r-7 {
  padding-right: 7px !important;
}
.padding-r-15 {
  padding-right: 15px !important;
}
.padding-r-10 {
  padding-right: 10px !important;
}
.padding-t-b-10 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-14 {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.fs-16 {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.fs-18 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.fs-20 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.fs-25 {
  font-size: 25px;
}
.f-right {
  float: right;
}
.bg-faded-white {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5)
}
.green {
  color: lightgreen;
}
.icon-flipped {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
}
.hlist {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.hlist li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
/*  */
```

Comment: Did you try javascript solution? `(/* empty content */) ? 'do this' : 'otherwise'`

Comment: @LaraBelle please read my question :)

Comment: Yes. I read it. If you use javascript. You can achieve what you want. You will just check for the content height. If it is greater than (zero or something) then pus some styles on it depends on how it will fit your design. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have modified your code here at [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/VWfeP1ShGE)

I've wrapped everything inside container into a wrapper which has minimum 100vh and has position relative which means the absolute footer will stay always at bottom of its relative container.

You should consider using **container** inside every independent section and wrapp everything into wrapper wchich would be like

```
<div class="wrapper">
<header><div class="container"></div></header>
<section class="content"><div class="container"></div></section>
<section class="another-section"><div class="container-fluid"></div></section>
<footer><div class="container"></div></footer>
</div>
```

It's useful especialy when there's another section that should be 100% wide - than you use **container-fluid**

Comment: But if the user collapses the window vertically, the footer overlaps the content :/

Comment: Try adding padding-bottom to wrapper like 80px (than you should use media queries to handle if footer gets bigger)

Answer (score 1):

`position:fixed` and `bottom:0` seems to be working for me. This might be because the background color of your footer is transparent and that you must be seeing content through your footer. Try the following code for your footer

```
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I miss comunicated, but I don't mean to use it in position fixed, I just want to keep it on the bottom of the page, but not keeping it when scrolling :)

Comment: When the page loads the footer is at the very bottom but when the page is scrolled you dont want it at the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

Try to position footer absolutely and define min-height equal 100vh for body:

```
body { background-color: #5f5; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
min-height: 100vh;}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vnvjwbms/)

Note: your HTML contained some errors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I can't make it up yesterday because I am too busy.

Here's an example of what I am trying to explain to you.

It's up to you on how you integrate with your app.

Basically, what I did is just check if the content is less than or equals to zero. Then add styles on your footer.

Try to add content. https://jsfiddle.net/4k5dsrmt/1/

Try to add some text on footer. It will be dynamic. And also dependable on your css fluidity.

> When I'm saying content I mean there is any .product-container.

You can also check if it has class or not. For me checking height is also as great as checking classes. Here's how you can check class.

`if(content.classList.contains('product-container'))`

```js
let content = document.getElementById('content'),
 footer = document.getElementById('footer'),
  checkContent = () => {
   if(content.clientHeight <= 0) {
      footer.style.position = 'absolute';
      footer.style.bottom = '0';
      footer.style.marginTop = '-' + footer.clientHeight;
    }
  };
  
checkContent();
  
window.onresize = checkContent;
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

footer#footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>

<footer id="footer">
  <p>This is your footer</p>
  <p>This is your footer</p>
  <p>This is your footer</p>
  <p>This is your footer</p>
  <p>This is your footer</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't want to add JS, thanks for your answer anyway :)

Comment: @Troyer Welcome. Atleast, you have an option if you need it ;)